# srcset and sizes not working in safari?

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, safari, responsive-images, srcset

For some reason the srcset and sizes aren't working correctly when viewing my site in Safari. It works fine for Chrome and Firefox but when viewing in Safari it loads the biggest image available even though the smaller ones which i've defined are there.

I'm using the metabox.io plugin for Wordpress which allows me to create image meta box and I'm uploading the images twice the size of homepage-image-lg for retina displays to load.

```
    <?php 
$homeimage1 = rwmb_meta( 'su_homepage-interior-design', array( 'size' => 'homepage-image-lg' ) );
$interiorDesign = reset($homeimage1); ?>            

                    <img class="scene_element scene_element--fadeinup"  src="<?php echo $interiorDesign['url'];?>" srcset="<?php echo $interiorDesign['srcset']; ?>" 

                    sizes="(max-width:767px) 767px, (min-width: 40.063em) and (min-width: 64em) and (max-width:74.9999em) 787px, (min-width: 75em) 787px, 787px" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" >
```

Why is this happening? Srcset and sizes should work for Safari right?

Source of image

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/interior-design-787x625.jpg" srcset=
  "/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/interior-design.jpg 1574w, /wp-content/uploads/2017/11/interior-design-768x610.jpg 768w, /wp-content/uploads/2017/11/interior-design-792x629.jpg 792w, /wp-content/uploads/2017/11/interior-design-787x625.jpg 787w"
  sizes=
  "(max-width:767px) 767px, (min-width: 40.063em) and (min-width: 64em) and (max-width:74.9999em) 787px, (min-width: 75em) 787px, 787px"
  itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us the content of `$interiorDesign['srcset'];`?

There are several useless parts in your `sizes`:

- `(max-width:767px) 767px`: it means the image is 767 pixels wide when the viewport is less or equal to `767px`
- `(min-width: 40.063em) and (min-width: 64em) and (max-width:74.9999em) 787px`: `(min-width: 40.063em)` is useless, because it is followed by `(min-width: 64em)`. So, the image is 787 pixels wide when the viewport is between `64em` and `74.9999em`. Let's suppose the root font-size is `16px` ([not always true](https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2016/03/people-don-t-change-the-default-16px-font-size-in-their-browser.html)), so `64em` means `1024px` and `74.9999em` means `1199.99px`. When the viewport is between these two values, the image is 787 pixels wide.
- `(min-width: 75em) 787px`: when the viewport is more than or equal to `1200px`, the image is 787 pixels wide.
- `787px`: finally, when no other media query matches (so when the viewport is between `768px` and `1023px`), the image is 787 pixels wide

So you image can have only two sizes: `767px` or `787px`, and your `sizes` attribute could be as simple as that:

`sizes="(max-width:767px) 767px, 787px"`

But anyway, these values are so close, I think that's probably not what you need.

Comment: Hey Nicolas, thank you for your answer. I've attached the content of $interiorDesign['srcset']; in my question - I hope this is helpful. I agree the sizes could be simplified and to be honest I think i had copied the sizes from another image and left the media queries on. However, the image being loaded is not the 768px image. Instead the original image is being loaded :(

Comment: Btw this is only happening on Safari 10.0.01.

Comment: So, it is the same issue as here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705380/safari-10-0-1-not-choosing-correct-image-from-srcset

Comment: Hi Nicolas, yes it is

Comment: So, I see someone told you it worked as intended in Safari 11.0.3, so maybe there was a bug in 11.0.1. Did you check what you got with 11.0.3?

Comment: I didn't find anything in https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&component=Images&product=WebKit&query_format=advanced&short_desc=srcset&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr