# Safari 10.0.1 not choosing correct image from srcset

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, safari, srcset

Safari is not handling srcset correctly for some of the images on my site and is completely ignoring the rules I set in the sizes attribute.

If you click on the link below and view it in Safari, you will see the images at the top are being displayed at their original sizes rather than the size I generated them as.

However, at the bottom of the page it's worked? And has been downloaded as westfield-house-large-bottom-955x637.jpg.

I've read that Safari is terrible at handling srcset and size attributes on images but in recent versions it's okay. I'm using Safari 10.0.1 which should have support for this.

Can anyone help me understand why the bottom image works but the ones at the top don't?

http://bluemoontesting.co.uk/susatchwell/projects/westfield-house/

I've been trying to figure this out for ages now and can't seem to get anywhere with it so If anyone can shed any light to why this is happening I'd be very grateful.

Many thanks,
Shaun

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but the images on your website are displaying on Safari as they are displaying on Chrome - it's displaying the generated sizes. Could it be a cache issue?

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for having a look for me. What version of Safari are you looking at it on? I've deleted the cache and I'm still seeing the original images being loaded. I'm using version 10.0.1.

Comment: OK. Well this is what I don't get. Surely if it's displaying correctly on 11.0.3 it should be displaying the same for the version I'm looking at it on. As they both have the same support?

Comment: I read that downloading Picturefill.js should resolve the issue with Safari but this hasn't made any difference.

Comment: @Shaun did you tries updating the safari.? you are using mac right.?

Comment: @weBer Yes, i'm using Safari 10.0.1 on a Mac. I could update to the latest version which would resolve this issue but this still doesn't solve the problem with 10.0.1.

Comment: On Sierra? because in safari 10.1 is fine... if for some odd reason you are in El Capitan which is 9.1 ...its still looks fine

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Safari 11.0.3. Is there any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Safari (tested only on: V16.0, on MacOS) evaluates `<img ... SRCSET=..` only on-after-load of the page, and does not re-evaluate the srcset when the page is resized. Chrome and FF do re-evaluation.
Didn't check `<picture>` tag.
So, if you care for resizing in Safari, Javascript or CSS will be your choice.
I didn't care, cause Safari means 95% iPhone or iPad.